# Does a one-to-one Relationship Mean Unnecessary Tables When Designing An SQL Database?

Tags: python, sql, database-design, sqlalchemy

My question is more conceptual than anything else. I'm designing the schema for a database that I am about to create using SQLAlchemy (a python toolkit for sql databases, http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), and I've come across a situation where, between two tables of the database, there exists a one-to-one relationship. To make this concrete, I have a table called "Identification", which contains two columns: 1) An internal id (used as the primary key), and 2) an object ID. This table has a one-to-one relationship to another table we can call "Analysis", which represents a unique look-up table to data which I have personally generated on each of these objects (through my research).

My question is, does the existence of a one-to-one relationship mean that I should combine "Identification" and "Analysis" into a single table? Every schema I've looked at for sql databases show one-to-many, or many-to-many type scenarios. Is there something conceptually wrong or bad about having a one-to-one relationship between tables of a database? The reason I'm even pursuing this is because this analysis that I've performed might be one of many types of analysis I'd like to do on each object, and it would be nice to have the identification table separated out from the data I get back from each analysis.

Any opinions or comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could easily go both ways.

In the case as you've described, where it seems it's one to one and the first table only contains identifiers, I would say that it's best to normalize the tables (combine them), because this allows you to remove a join from what would otherwise be required in effectively every query.

In general, I would call this true anytime there is an effective 1 to 1 relationship. That being said, there is another variation of this, the 0..1 to 1. In this case, it may be possible for example, to have a row in table a that either has 1 row in table b, or does not. In this case, it's advantageous to keep them separate because otherwise you have columns that may not apply to every row and just sit empty.

Generally, in designing your database, ask yourself the question "What am I gaining by keeping these separate, vs what am I losing if I don't merge them". In the first case, you gain little and lose performance.

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks. I think I will be keeping them separate then, because these multiple analyses that I was referring to may not be run systematically on all possible objects. They may only be run on a subpopulation of them, creating the situation you're describing as 1 to 1 or 0.